# Primary frequency of triangular wave from xarray dataarray

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, python-xarray

I've a dataset that is a triangular wave sampled at a regular time period, currently in an xarray dataarray.

Is there a (relatively simply) way to determine the primary frequency of the wave in python? I've looked around at xarray, pandas and scipy but not really made any progress.

UPDATE:

I've made a little progress with this:

```
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq

yf = fft(data.values)
N = len(data.values)
xf = fftfreq(N, 1000)[1:100]
plt.plot(xf, np.abs(yf[1:100]))
```

Comment: I would try to calculate the frequency based on the wave peaks: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

Comment: Thanks, @Mr.T, I didn't know about that function. I've only been trying FFT.